# Use variable in other variable name

Tags: powershell, variables

I need values of variables which these variable names are concatened by another variable's value.

e.g.

```
$GV_R32_var = "testtesttest"
$m = "R32"
(Get-Variable -Name "`$GV_$($m)_var").Value
```

I receive following error message:

```
+ (Get-Variable -Name "`$GV_$($m)_var").Value
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ($GV_R32_var:String) [Get-Variable], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetVariableCommand
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're really close!

The variable **name** doesn't include a dollar!

So your code:

```
(Get-Variable -Name "`$GV_$($m)_var").Value
```

Becomes:

```
(Get-Variable -Name "GV_$($m)_var").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it too:

```
Invoke-Expression $"GV_$m`_var"
```